# VB.Net TCP failing to connect to socket on local connection

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I'm having an issue establishing a connection to my `TcpClient` using the local server address of `127.0.0.1` and port `1000`. It attempts to establish a connection and then hits my `Catch SocketException` that it is unable to find a server.

I've set breakpoints and have went through the code line by line and it catches my exception once the line `NetStream = Client.GetStream()` is called from within my `Try/Catch` after pressing my button `btnStart`. Showing that no connection is being established at all. Why is this?

```vb
Public Class frmForm1

    Dim Client As TcpClient 
    Dim connection As Socket 
    Dim NetStream As NetworkStream
```

```vb
Private Sub btnStartClient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartClient.Click

    Try

        txtLog.Text &= "Attempting to connect" 

        Client = New TcpClient()
        Client.Connect(txtAddress.Text, CInt(txtPort.Text))

        NetStream = Client.GetStream() 


    ' Catch errors in trying to connect to server
    Catch SocketEx As SocketException
        txtLog.Text &= "Cannot find server" 
    End Try

End Sub
```

It shouldn't be throwing my exception and then creating my NetworkStream Reader/Writer objects and print that they were created. As well as setting up the listening thread. However, I cannot even get that far as my `Catch SocketException` is called at the line `NetStream = Client.GetStream()`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 2 threads. One for the server to listen and one for the clinet to connect. Make sure to call `.Start()` on the `TcpListener` object (`Server.Start()` in your case) before trying to connect the client to the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable either a server or client connection"? A connection always requires at least 2 endpoints. You can start as many server connections as you want, but you need at least one. When having these server connections, you can connect as many clients as you want to different servers. But to establish a connection, you need to connect at least one client to one server. Then the server and client can exchange message in both ways.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear that!